# unexpected token `fi' in script

Tags: bash, syntax

Whenever I run the bash script I encounter this problem:

> ```
> LRU.sh: line 121: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
> ```

The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i numOfPageRRef=0
declare -i numOfFrames=$1
declare -i a=0
declare -i k=0
declare -i c=0
declare -i q
declare -i c1=0



OIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
read line < Input2.csv

for val in $line
do
pageRef[$numOfPageRRef]=$val

((numOfPageRRef++))
done
#echo ${pageRef[@]}

q[$k]=${pageRef[$k]}  #chck here
echo ${q[$k]}
((c++))
((k++))


for((i=1;i<numOfPageRRef;i++))
do


c1=0
for((j=0;j<numOfFrames;j++))
do


if (( ${pageRef[$i]} -ne ${q[$j]} ))
then
((c1++))
fi
done

if (( c1 -eq numOfFrames ))
then

((c++))

if (( k -lt numOfFrames )) ;then

q[$k]=${pageRef[$i]}
((k++))

for((j=0;j<numOfFrames;j++))
do
echo ${q[$j]}
done

else 
for((r=0;r<numOfFrames;r++))
do

c2[r]=0
for((j=i-1;j<numOfPageRRef;j--))
do

if (( ${q[$r]} -ne ${p[$j]} ))   
then
((c2[r]++))
else break
fi

done
done

for((r=0;r<numOfFrames;r++))
do
t4=${c2[r]}
b[$r]=$t4

for((r=0;r<numOfFrames;r++)) 
do

for((j=r;j<numOfFrames;j++))
do

if (( ${b[$r} -lt ${b[$j]} ))
then

t=${b[r]}
t2=${b[j]}
b[$r]=$t2
b[$j]=$t

fi   
done
done

for((r=0;r<numOfFrames;r++))
do

if (( ${c2[$r]} -eq ${b[0]} ))
then

t3=${p[$i]}
q[$r]=$t3

fi
echo ${q[$r]}

done

#echo 

fi
fi
done

echo "The no of page fault is $c"
```

Comment: Fix your indentation. It'll help in general (though not here). Get an editor that does syntax highlighting. It will also help in general and *also* helps here as it gets confused (at least vim does) just a few lines after your problem. Also use http://www.shellcheck.net as it will catch a number of problems (once you fix the big one that makes its parser choke).

Comment: indent means bro? software is it>?

Comment: It would help to know which line is line 121.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style

Comment: @Guido That can't be since there is no `fi` at the end of file (but `done` and `echo`.

Comment: @Jens You're right, I made a mistake while pasting this into my editor.

Comment: You only have 96 lines of code in the question. We need to see your actual code, and it needs to be properly indented.

Comment: Keith this is my actual code.I'm duing LRU page replacement algrorithm in bash script. I have to just hv to send the numOfFrames by the command ./LRU.sh 4 , than it should calculate the number of page fault by display the frame content

Comment: This cannot be the actual code that produced the error message you report. The error message refers to line 121, but there are only 96 lines in the code you posted. Furthermore, you **really** need to properly indent your code if you expect anyone to look at it.

Comment: Wokay bro i will properly indent my code.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is because you missed a **done** closing statement, when i remade all the syntax in your code i was able to see it, its in the bottom. so here is your code without the error.

**P.S**

*In the future please pay attention on the **syntax**, it makes big difference while reading the code.*

```
OIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
read line < Input2.csv

for val in $line
do
    pageRef[$numOfPageRRef]=$val
    ((numOfPageRRef++))
done
#echo ${pageRef[@]}
q[$k]=${pageRef[$k]}  #check here
echo ${q[$k]}
((c++))
((k++))
for((i=1;i<numOfPageRRef;i++))
do
    c1=0
    for((j=0;j<numOfFrames;j++))
    do
        if (( ${pageRef[$i]} -ne ${q[$j]} ))
            then
            ((c1++))
        fi
    done
    if (( c1 -eq numOfFrames ))
        then
        ((c++))
        if (( k -lt numOfFrames ))
            then
            q[$k]=${pageRef[$i]}
            ((k++))

            for((j=0;j<numOfFrames;j++))
            do
                echo ${q[$j]}
            done

        else 
            for((r=0;r<numOfFrames;r++))
            do
                c2[r]=0
                for((j=i-1;j<numOfPageRRef;j--))
                do
                    if (( ${q[$r]} -ne ${p[$j]} ))   
                        then
                        ((c2[r]++))
                    else break
                    fi
                done
            done
            for((r=0;r<numOfFrames;r++))
            do
                t4=${c2[r]}
                b[$r]=$t4
                for((r=0;r<numOfFrames;r++))
                do
                    for((j=r;j<numOfFrames;j++))
                    do
                        if (( ${b[$r]} -ne ${b[$j]} ))
                            then
                            t=${b[r]}
                            t2=${b[j]}
                            b[$r]=$t2
                            b[$j]=$t
                        fi   
                    done 
                done
                for((r=0;r<numOfFrames;r++))
                do
                    if (( ${c2[$r]} -eq ${b[0]} ))
                        then
                        t3=${p[$i]}
                        q[$r]=$t3
                    fi
                    echo ${q[$r]}
                done
            done #Here You forgot the done!!!!!
        fi
    fi
done
    echo "The no of page fault is $c"
```